# Subclass implementations of generics methods

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I'm trying to make a parent class for converters avoiding repeated code, so I started doing the java abstract class I provide here:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils;

public abstract class AbstractUIConverter {
    protected abstract <UIO, DTO> DTO toDto(final UIO input);

    protected abstract <DTO, UIO> UIO toUIO(final DTO input);

    protected <UIO, DTO> List<DTO> toDtoList(final List<UIO> inputList) {
        return convertList(inputList, true);
    }

    protected <DTO, UIO> List<UIO> toUIOList(final List<DTO> inputList) {
        return convertList(inputList, false);
    }

    private <I, O> List<O> convertList(final List<I> inputList, final boolean toDto) {
        List<O> returnList;
        if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(inputList)) {
            returnList = new ArrayList<O>(inputList.size());
            O temp;
            for (final I inputElem : inputList) {
                if(toDto) {
                    temp = toDto(inputElem);
                } else {
                    temp = toUIO(inputElem);
                }
                returnList.add(temp);
            }
        } else {
            returnList = new ArrayList<O>(0);
        }
        return returnList;
    }
}
```

The problem is when coming to subclassing. When I make a subclass extending this class and replace the type of the input parameter called 'input' in the method signature to override either toDto() or toUIO() like this:

```
@Override
protected <UIO, DTO> DTO toDto(SomeTypeUIO input) {
```

it appears a message:

> The method toDto(SomeTypeUIO) of type SubclassConverter must override or implement a supertype method

If I replace in the  the first type:

```
protected <SomeTypeUIO, DTO> DTO toDto(SomeTypeUIO input) {
```

it appears this warning:

> The type parameter SomeTypeUIO is hiding the type

which obviously is what I don't want.

I have tried parameterizing AbstractUIConverter but this is worse. I also have tried messing with "extends" inside  syntax.

My goal is to define the types in the subclass, so the functions for converting lists are all made in the parent.

I would appreciate help and advice, or some resources for looking in the web.

Comment: Why don't you make the class generic? `public abstract class AbstractUIConverter<UIO, DTO>`

Comment: Have you consider mapstruct (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mapstruct/info )?

Comment: @Flown I tried ("I have tried parameterizing AbstractUIConverter") but there were messages telling me the class generic type parameters were hiding the methods type parameters. If I remove the type parameters from the methods it's almost impossible to make convertList in one only implementation as I wanted

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera Initially, I can't use third-party source code. This is only allowed if we have no other means of achieving the task and after discussing with a software architecture department in the company. It's a long process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right approach would be:

```
public abstract class AbstractUIConverter<UIO, DTO> {
  protected abstract DTO toDto(final UIO input);

  protected abstract UIO toUIO(final DTO input);

  protected List<DTO> toDtoList(final List<UIO> inputList) {
    return convertList(inputList, this::toDto);
  }

  protected List<UIO> toUIOList(final List<DTO> inputList) {
    return convertList(inputList, this::toUIO);
  }

  private <I, O> List<O> convertList(final List<I> inputList, final Function<I, O> function) {
    if(inputList.isEmpty()) {
      return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    List<O> returnList = new ArrayList<>(inputList.size());
    for(I input : inputList) {
      returnList.add(function.apply(input));
    }
    return returnList;
  }
}
```

---

You already have a distinction in your method call how to transform your data.

< Java 8:

```
public abstract class AbstractUIConverter<UIO, DTO> {
  protected abstract DTO toDto(final UIO input);

  protected abstract UIO toUIO(final DTO input);

  protected List<DTO> toDtoList(final List<UIO> inputList) {
    return convertList(inputList, new Function<UIO, DTO>() {
      @Override
      public DTO apply(UIO input) {
        return AbstractUIConverter.this.toDto(input);
      }
    });
  }

  protected List<UIO> toUIOList(final List<DTO> inputList) {
    return convertList(inputList, new Function<DTO, UIO>() {
      @Override
      public UIO apply(DTO input) {
        return AbstractUIConverter.this.toUIO(input);
      }
    });
  }

  private <I, O> List<O> convertList(final List<I> inputList, final Function<I, O> function) {
    if(inputList.isEmpty()) {
      return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    List<O> returnList = new ArrayList<>(inputList.size());
    for(I input : inputList) {
      returnList.add(function.apply(input));
    }
    return returnList;
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks good. The 'this::' notation is for Java 1.8 exclusively or not?

Comment: Yes, it is a method reference.

Comment: I haven't tried yet, but it compiles and it seems to be the best solution. I'm having problems now with Sprint inejction, but when resolved I expect this to work. Thanks

Comment: I love your solution, but I must make one statement for another readers. The solution for Java < 1.8 is not worth since Function<I,O> exists only in Java 1.8 following the Java API documentation (read the "since" line): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html

Comment: What is stopping you from creating your own `Function<I, O>` interface?